# python3.2)How to find weekday between two dates?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to get same weekdays for first date given and duration is between first date and second date. first date is date(2011, 01, 11) second date is today.
`from datetime import date
    """
    (date(2011, 10, 15))
    """
    samewkdays=date.weekday()
    print(samewkdays) #5`

the output has to be dates that month and weekday are same with first date. Since I'm rarely knew about datetime function I can't even think further from here. I'll deeply apprecite your any advices, help me!

Answer (score 2):

I hope that's what you mean. I also provide tests for clarity. I just iterate until we reached `today` or switched a month.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date

def get_month_dates_with_same_weekday(dt, dt_end=None):
    mon = dt.month
    rv = []
    dt_end = date.today() if dt_end is None else dt_end
    while dt.month == mon and dt <= dt_end:
        rv.append(dt)
        dt = dt + timedelta(days=7)
    return rv


def check(dt1, dt2):
    assert dt1.weekday() == dt.weekday()
    assert dt1.month == dt.month


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dt1 = date(2011, 10, 15)
    rv = get_month_dates_with_same_weekday(dt1)
    for dt in rv:
        check(dt, dt1)
    dt2 = date(2011, 10, 1)
    for dt in get_month_dates_with_same_weekday(dt2):
        check(dt, dt2)

    rv = get_month_dates_with_same_weekday(dt2, date(2011, 10, 2)) 
    assert len(rv) == 1 and rv[0] == dt2

    rv = get_month_dates_with_same_weekday(dt2, date(2011, 10, 9)) 
    assert len(rv) == 2 and rv[0] == dt2 and rv[1] == date(2011, 10, 8)
```